# Horizon entry, Meszaros suppression and start of perturbation growth

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, perturbation-theory, structure-formation

I thought that the onset of perturbation growth was determined by horizon entry of the perturbation (because there won't be a gravitational collapse of an over dense region not causally connected to the background). But apparently there can be super horizon perturbation growth. But looking at plots of growth for the different modes (Dodelson), they still start at different times. Horizon entry rather determines whether the perturbation suffers Meszaros suppression.

What then, if not horizon entry, causes the onset of the perturbation growth for a mode $k$. They don't all just start after inflasion..? (doesn't seem like it)

Edit:
I've learned that super horizon growth is a consequence of working in, for example, the comoving gauge. In gauge-independent curvature-perturbations, perturbations stay constant until horizon entry, as you'd expect. Still, in the newtonian conformal gauge, this gauge-invariant quantity reduces to the over density (if I understood it correctly).

My new question is then: Why is there a delay in the Meszaros suppression, working in this gauge?